# Terraform Snowflake module creation impossible - Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I have this working code below.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "chanzuckerberg/snowflake"
      version = "0.25.36"
    }
  }
}
provider "snowflake" {
  alias = "sys_admin"
  role  = "SYSADMIN"
  username = "tf-snow"
  private_key = var.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
  account = "KY88548"
}
resource "snowflake_warehouse" "star_warehouse" {
  provider       = snowflake.sys_admin
  name           = "STAR_WAREHOUSE"
  warehouse_size = "XSmall"

  auto_suspend = 60
}
```

Note that I have to provide an argument, provider = snowflake.sys_admin or it throws an error.

Now when I am making a module in subfolder, I have this code in the subfolder.

```
variable "sf_provider" {
    type = string
}
resource "snowflake_warehouse" "star_warehouse" {
  provider       = var.sf_provider
  name           = "STAR_WAREHOUSE"
  warehouse_size = "XSmall"

  auto_suspend = 60
}
```

The code in my root directory looks like this

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "chanzuckerberg/snowflake"
      version = "0.25.36"
    }
  }
}

provider "snowflake" {
  username = "tf-snow"
  account = "KY88548"
  region = "ap-southeast-2"

  alias = "sys_admin"
  role  = "SYSADMIN"
  private_key = var.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY
}
module "snowflake_resources" {
  source = "./snowflake_resources"
  sf_provider = snowflake.sys_admin
}
```

This now gives me the following error.

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/snowflake: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have
│ a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/snowflake
│ 
│ Did you intend to use chanzuckerberg/snowflake? If so, you must specify
│ that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see
│ which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/snowflake, run the
│ following command:
│     terraform providers
```

is there a way I can create these resources without specifying the provider argument or at least have the option to pass it as an argument to my modules?

Comment: Each module should specify `required_providers`.

Comment: Yes this worked. Seems strange to me, but it worked

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Each Terraform module must declare which providers it requires, so that Terraform can install and use them. Provider requirements are declared in a required_providers block.

So, you need to ensure that `required_providers` is declared in each module.

Comment: hmm but when I create aws modules, I am able to just define the aws provider in the root module and then make subsequent modules without redefining the aws provider, am I misunderstanding something?